# Two-way binding doesn't work in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this code

```
export class TestController {
    constructor() {
        this.socket = io();
        this.movies = {};
        this.socket.emit('getAllMovies', '');
        this.socket.on('allMovies', this.listMovies.bind(this));
    }

    listMovies(data){
        this.movies = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(this.movies);
    }
}
```

and view (using controllerAs syntax)

```
<div>
{{ctrl.movies}}
</div>
```

When I open the page, it shows {}, then data from websocket incomes (correctly), biding to this.movies, and nothing changes. Looks like two-way biding is broken. Anyone has idea why?

Comment: You are using angular 2?

Comment: I believe the problem is not w/ ES6 but comes from the fact that angular change detection mechanism is not aware about your socket and the fact that it has to run digest loop.

Comment: @JohnnyJohn I'm using angular1, forgotten to mention

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/?redirect_from_locale=ru Socket io here was wrapped with a service that manually call `$apply` on every socket event.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko please post your answer with this link, so I can mark it. It solved my problem

Comment: @Raston BTW angular 2 handles this w/o additional wrapper utilizing very clever concept called Zone. There are a lot of blog posts out there explaining what was the problem with angular1.x change detection and how it was solved using Zones. Worth reading. :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko We have played some with angular2 and yeah, it is cool, but using beta version in production app is risky. But, angular2 is much simpler, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not w/ ES6 but comes from the fact that angular change detection mechanism is not aware about your socket and the fact that it has to run digest loop.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/). Socket io here was wrapped with a service that manually calls $apply on every socket event.

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        //NB!
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```